# Writing on console window overlay?

Tags: c#, console-application

What I can't seem to find out is if it is possible in a C# console application to write text in some kind of layer over the top of the existing window and text for say a progress bar or information.

I've seen power shell cmdlets that do it, to display a progress bar and then when its finished the progress bar goes away and whatever was underneath is visible. The bars I've seen also stay in position even if additional console output causes the window to scroll.

Anyone any ideas?

Edit: Heres an example of powershell doing it using Write-Progress

http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-76-18-metablogapi/8726.WES_2D00_1_2D00_29_2D00_11_2D00_2_5F00_2587E97F.jpg

Comment: I would guess this is done by clearing the screen every time the progress bar updates and re-displaying, but maybe there is another way.

Comment: You can pretty much do whatever the heck you want with `Console.SetCursorPosition`.  Oftentimes when something appears to be "on top" of something else it just means that the program is storing the information in memory needed to re-create what it previously overwrite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite possibly they're using [Console Screen Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That is, they save the current buffer and create a new one for the application to use. When the application is done, it puts the original screen buffer back.

I wrote an article about using Console Screen Buffers in .NET some years ago. Check out http://www.devsource.com/article2/0,1895,2011496,00.asp

Full source is available at http://www.mischel.com/pubs/consoledotnet/consoledotnet.zip

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! Will give this a read, but looks like it will do what I asked for, thanks :)

Comment: unfort. ur devsource link seems to be dead. i have found the magic spot in the powershell source:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressPane.cs